# How to prevent fastclick from showing a loading dialog in jquery mobile?

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile, cordova, click

In my Phonegap application for android I have used the fastclick library for eliminating the 300ms delay , the problem is that when i click a button a loading dialog appears as the following image . How can i prevent this loading dialog  from appearing ??

I have read the fastclick java script file line by line and there is no explicit calling for $.mobile.loading( "show") .. Please help me

Here how i use the fastclick in my app

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fastclick.js"></script> 
<script>

 $(function() {FastClick.attach(document.body);}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">Main</div>
<div data-role="content"> 
<div>
<a href="Page1.html"  data-transition="none" class="ui-btn" data-role="button"  data-       theme="none" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" ><img  id="Page1_IMG"  src="images/P1.png" /></a><BR>
<font color="white"  size="6px"> Page1  </font>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: @OmarHow?? and from where ? there is no  loader in the fastclick.js

Comment: @OmarCan you help me more Please??

Comment: try this `<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="jQuery-Mobile.js"></script>`

Comment: @OmarThis will  turnoff loader only on the index page ? or on  the whole app ? because in another page in my app  i need to show a loader

Comment: this will disable loader on all pages. in this case you need to disable/enable it based on page. it needs different js to achieve it.

Comment: @OmrCan you help me in writing this js  to disable/enable loader based on page Please?

Comment: @OmarPlease can you help me ?? its very important to solve this issue

Comment: the loader appears when you move to another page?

Comment: @OmarYes when i click the button to go to Page1 a loader appears

Comment: @OmarSorry for late response I have encountered a problem in internet connection..  can you help me more Please ??